# Multiple prepared statements, keep alive until finish page

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Lets say a have Web page with some classes. One is loaded Mysqli connect it to DB at the beginning and keep connected. Now question is:

Is good solution make in (example setting class) prepared statement for calling value from DB table 'settings' and keep it open (statement) until finish (at footer close statement and connection) or just load all data from 'settings' DB table to array() in php and just call it from array not binding it from DB.

Second question is if I have statement open may I open another statement for another class (example class for calling text from DB) and do it same like in previous example? And than, of course close it at finish page.

Is there any performance or security problem, you can see there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As far as I know, nobody is doing it this way. Mostly because the real benefit from the multiple execution is not that grand as some imagine, and just doesn't worth the trouble. For the short primary key lookups run in small numbers (several dozens at max) you'll hardly be able to tell the difference.
   (However, there are no arguments against such practice either - you can make it this way, with single statement prepared/multiple executions, if you wish).
2. Yet single query that is fetching no more than couple hundreds of records still would be faster than separate queries (even prepared) to get the same amount. So, as long as your settings keep at moderate amount, it's better to get them all at once.
3. Yes, of course you can have as many statements prepared as you need.
   (The only problem could be with *fetching* results. You have to always get_result/store_result, to make sure there are no results left pending and preventing other queries to run, either regular or prepared).

Answer (score 1):

The statement executes as one SQL statement over your DB connection. It's not going to keep going back to the database and grabbing a single row one at a time, so don't worry about that.

In general, you should be loading everything into some data structure. If your query is returning more data than you need, then that's something you need to fix in your query. Don't run SQL that returns a huge set of data, then rely on PHP to go through it row by row and perform some hefty operations on it. Just write SQL that gets what you need in the first place. I realize this isn't always possible, but when people talk about optimizing their website, query optimization is usually at/near the top of that list, so it's pretty important.

You're definitely supposed to execute multiple statements. It's silly to keep opening and closing entire db connections before getting any data.

Comment: It's always nice when someone gives an actual comment explaining a downvote. I've spent significant time developing database drivers and am addressing the questions in the post, so it's not helping anyone to see a reasonable answer downvoted without explanation.

Comment: this question is entirely and solely on using prepared statements. And your answer seems misses this point entirely as well.

Comment: He asked if he should just keep his prepared statement open, and I said there's no good reason to. He asked if he should load the data into a PHP array from the start, and I said that's usually a good idea, and if he thinks it would be too big an array usually that means to re-evaluate your query. He asked if he can have multiple prepared statements open, and I said yes. How is this off-topic?

Comment: Well, may be I took your answer wrong. But what does "opening and closing entire db connections" to do with the question?

Comment: And "It's not going to keep going back to the database and grabbing a single row one at a time" too. For the prepared statement it looks like quite contrary - it is indeed goes back to the database and grabbing a single row one at a time when you need another setting.

Comment: I think you're assuming he's talking about _executing_ the same prepared statement multiple times, but from the initial question, he could just be asking if he ought to fetch() through his results as he needs them. Why are you assuming expert-level competency from someone asking if he can have multiple statements? This is clearly an introductory question.

Comment: I see no evidence for such interpretation. However, I see your reason now. I think you are making too many assumptions. To ask if it's all right to keep a statement prepared during script lifetime is a legitimate question and I wouldn't take it for another unless proven otherwise

Comment: Ok guys... Your fighting giving me more explanation of my question, but... It is not possible just query everything what I need, because I don't want what I need. It is class working for all my project and it start with main page and include modules and and mode pages... So if I need some setting in exact module I have to call it. And here is where the question stands... OK settings is about hundreds of rows.. but what about text of multilanguage storet in DB where is large amout of data to call (if I store it to array and call it at begining...) Any ideas ..